# Add rightBarButtonItems to NavBar in UISplitViewController (swift 3)

Tags: swift, uinavigationbar, rightbarbuttonitem, navigationitem

I am trying to set a custom BarButtonItem to my NavigationBar  of my DetailsVC in my UISplitViewController with these two lines of code:

```
let barbuttonitem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Hi", style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [barbuttonitem]
```

but somehow nothing happens. When i create a new project and add these 2 lines of codes for my navBar it works, but in my real App it doesn't.

Thanks for your help

Comment: where do you call `navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems` ?

Comment: all in the ViewDidLoad of the ViewController